# Is it possible to set a spending limit on Heroku?

Tags: heroku

I have a Rails app deployed to Heroku on the Cedar Stack. I'd like to start running a nightly scheduled task, but in order to add the scheduler add-on, I need to give Heroku my credit card details.

I'm not sure how much this will end up costing, though, so I'd like to be able to set a spending limit on my Heroku account.

In other words, I'd like to be able to say "Please don't let me use dyno hours that will cost me more than $XXX per month".

Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I asked this same question on the [Heroku forums](https://discussion.heroku.com/t/is-it-possible-to-set-a-spending-limit-on-heroku/317/7). The answer is no, there is currently no way of setting a spending limit.

It is a feature they are considering implementing, though.

Answer (score 1):

No, it's currently not possible to manage your cost natively with Heroku because they don't offer such feature at the moment.

However, there are a few third party solutions available. For example, the [Heroku add-on cloudvertical](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/cloudvertical) claims to be able to track and analyse cloud infrastructure usage and costs.

There is also [HireFire, a dyno manager](http://hirefire.io/).

If you search for Heroku scaling, or Heroku autoscaling, you will find a few solutions.

Disclaimer: I haven't tried them.